# MIB integration with SNMP Agent in java

Tags: java, snmp, snmp4j

How a MIB is used during the SNMP Agent development in java means How MIB integrate with SNMP Agent in java so that SNMP Agent can communicate with MIB or vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of MIB's there may be 2 types of MIB OID's are possible

1) Scalar
2) Tabular

I hope you have enough knowledge about these & you can refer below code for reference

public class Mib implements MOGroup {

String sysDescr = client.getAsString(new OID(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0"));

}

And for and for more details have a look at "http://shivasoft.in/blog/java/snmp/create-snmp-client-in-java-using-snmp4j/".